# Wordpress Blank Page with header/sidebar/footer of my template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

How can i create a page in a directory like  **`public_html/test1`** that has a single **blank page** with the **`header/sidebar/footer` of my actual template**.
I can only see the header, no sidebar , no content ( by content i mean "Hello." ).
I'm using twenty fourteen template.

This is the php code i am using:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: My own page!
* Description: I made a page!
*/ 
require (dirname(dirname( __FILE__ )).'/wp-load.php');
get_header();   
get_sidebar();
?>
Hello.
```

Note: if i *delete* the `the_content();` `get_footer();`  , then  the header ONLY appears but without format.

*Any help deeply appreciated*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content isn't appearing because there's no loop inside your template. Please add this code inside your template and move your template file to the 'page-templates' folder inside the twentyfourteen theme.

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: My own page!
* Description: I made a page!
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

p.s. you can remove the div's if you'd like to.

Comment: i am trying to make a static page in a "test543" folder, i dont want to touch any other files on my website. i only want to show the header sidebar and footer...(AND ofc my content on that specific page for example "hello.") how can i achieve that ?

Comment: If you check your web page using the Developer Tools, you'll notice that both the 'Hello' text and the sidebar are being echo'd out on the page. There's something wrong with your CSS because of which both the sidebar and the text aren't appearing. 

Just to test, you can add the 'float: right;' property to the css of '#secondary' element and your sidebar will start appearing on the right side of the page. Add this right above the </head> tag in your header.php file and delete it once you've checked: 

     <style>
     #secondary {
          float: right;
     }
     </style>

Comment: Okay, here's a trick. Go to the style.css file inside the twentyfourteen theme folder and near line 3629, find `.site:before` and add the following property to its style:

`display: none;`

Comment: Or if you want to quickly test, simply add this code right above the `</head>` tag inside your header.php file: `<style>#secondary { float: right !important; } .site:before { display: none !important; }</style>`

Comment: @Shiro Please check my reply above yours. You need to add the `float: right;` property to the styles for the `#secondary` element.

Comment: Should the bar be aligned to left?

Comment: Can you edit your main question and post the exact code which you're using inside the template file for http://shiro-desu.com/ and http://shiro-desu.com/ttt/?

Comment: http://pastie.org/9560480  this is the code on \wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\index.php if thats what you asked for.

Comment: @Shiro Okay, do this now. Go to http://pastie.org/9560485, copy the code and paste it inside your template file as it is, without making any modifications, and save it. Next, log into your Wordpress dashboard and create a new page. When you're creating a new page, look at the 'Page Attributes' tab under the 'Publish' button and from the 'Template' dropdown, select the 'My own page!' template. Next, add any content inside the content editor and simply publish the page. Now when you'll view the page, you'll see the content which you added, through the Wordpress dashboard, appearing on the page.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try and do this, but is this the only way? cant i just have a .php file and open it and just load header and sidebar from there like i am trying to do ? with your solution i will have to login to my wordpress account every time to edit my page right ? but what i am trying to do is have a static page that can be moved from directory to directory ( or even possibly different wordpress website on another server? ) . but i guess it aint that simple ?...

Comment: That is possible as well. You can simply use this code in your template file then and replace `//Add any content here` with your content: http://pastie.org/9560506

Comment: o wow. it worked ! :D thank you so so much for your time man. you spent a lot of time to help me , im really thankful. :) finally done it

Comment: um.. i was just wondering how can i remove the format of "main content" on my page ? http://shiro-desu.com/ttt/ here is a sample code http://pastie.org/9560712 , you can see that it makes it look kind of funny.. Note: i am going to sleep sorry for any late response if you answer me back today.